# How to fix "value used in formula is wrong data type" error when trying to convert a range into an array?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a udf to convert the entered range into an array, and if done successfully, the function will return "worked" into the cell. However, it keeps returning #VALUE!, and says:

> "a value used in the formula is of the wrong data type."

```
Function test(rng As Range) As String

Dim Arr() As Variant
Arr = Range(rng)

test="worked"

End Function
```

Answer (score 3):

use:

```
Function test(rng As Range) As String

    Dim Arr As Variant
    Arr = rng

    test = "worked"

End Function
```

Comment: Note: what's making this work is the implicit default member call of the `Range` class, through implicit let-coercion happening in the `Arr = rng` assignment. A more explicit version of this code would be `Arr = rng.Value`, where `Range.Value` is documented to yield a 2D variant array given a multiple-cell range. The implicit code here is `Arr = rng.[_Default]`, where `_Default` is the hidden/undocumented default member of the `Range` class. `Arr` will not be a variant array if `rng` only has 1 cell.

Answer (score 1):

Was typing this as a comment, but will put as an answer due to content.  Note that @DisplayName gave the appropriate answer to resolve your issue.

In your code you use 'Range()` with inappropriate syntax.  Here are some examples of appropriate range references:

```
Sheets("Name).Range("A1")  'Uses cell A1 on sheets Name
Sheets("Name").Cells(1,1)  'Just like the above, calls cell A1

i = 1
Sheets("Name).Range("A" & i)  'Ampersand joins the variable i (typically used to iterate through a loop) with the column "A"

Sheets("Name").Range("Cat")  'Uses a named range, where cat is predefined and is on sheets Name

With Sheets("Name")
    Set rng = .Range(.Cells(1,1),.Cells(2,2)) 'Creates a range from A1 to B2... note the dots to make them use the appropriate sheet 
End With
rng.value = "Cat"  'Each cell in the range will have "Cat" input
```